# How to create URN for Revit File from revit plugin or using Forge apis

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

I need to know is there any possibility to create the URN from Revit file which is in BIM 360 Design.

I have Model GUID and Project GUID in my hand.

Replays will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While initializing the cloud collaboration in BIM360 Design via Revit's Collaborate button in `Collaborate tab > Manage Collaboration panel`, Revit will upload your model, and publish the first version to BIM360 Document Management(well known as Docs) during the procedure.

After completing the initialization, you can call Forge DM APIs to obtain model URNs in your BIM360 project, such as [projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) or [GET Versions](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/?_ga=2.69623760.1996415122.1543328615-671758876.1517749558). Afterward, iterate items in the API response and find a version which matches the Model GUID and Project GUID you mentioned. It will look like this, and the id value is the URN you wanted.

```
{  
   "type":"versions",
   "id":"urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.abcd1234?version=1",
   "attributes":{  
      "name":"fileName.rvt",
      "displayName":"fileName.rvt",
      ...
      "mimeType":"application/vnd.autodesk.r360",
      "storageSize":123456,
      "fileType":"rvt",
      "extension":{  
         "type":"versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel",
         ....
         "data":{  
            ...
            "projectGuid":"48da72af-3aa6-4b76-866b-c11bb3d53883",
            ....
            "modelGuid":"e666fa30-9808-42f4-a05b-8cb8da576fe9",
            ....
         }
      }
   },
   ....
}
```

BTW, you might be interested in this blog topic [Accessing BIM 360 Design models on Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-bim-360-design-models-revit)

Comment: Is there any event in Revit which occurs after initialization ?

Comment: By using the URN is it possible to view the model in BIM 360 FORGE viewer

Answer (score 2):

I shared Eason's answer on [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) as well, in the discussion on [Accessing BIM360 Models](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/12/forge-devcon-keynote-and-bim360-model-access.html#3).